# Unable to find a form for this button

Tags: custom-button

So i have put together this button:
[image]

..with this code:

```
    {!REQUIRESCRIPT ("/soap/ajax/37.0/connection.js")} 
var records = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Case)}; 
var ESB = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.ESB__c)};
var newRecords = []; 
  for (var n=0; n<records.length; n++) { 
          var c = new sforce.SObject("Case");
          c.id = records[n]; 
          c.RecordTypeId = '012C0000000CAUP';
          c.Opportunity_Status__c = "Sold";
          c.Deployed_Set_Quantity__c = ESB.Bundle_Count__c;
          newRecords.push(c); 
  }
result = sforce.connection.create(newRecords);
```

However, when trying to use it I get a popup error message that states "Unable to find a form for this button".

The idea is that this should be a Related List button on the ESB record that creates a new case with some details in it.

What am i doing wrong?

Thank you,

Zan

Comment: Try adding {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/33.0/apex.js")} along with connection.js you can adjust the version as per your need for apex.js

Comment: Thanks, Nachiket, but that didn't work. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following code. Assuming in Case, there is a lookup field called ESB__c.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/40.0/connection.js")}
var cs = new sforce.SObject("Case");
cs.Subject = "New Case";
cs.Origin = "Phone";
cs.ESB__c = '{!ESB__c.Id}';
var result = sforce.connection.create([cs]);
```

> To open the newly created case page in edit mode, you have to redirect the URL to `/<newly created Case id>/e`

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/40.0/connection.js")}
var cs = new sforce.SObject("Case");
cs.Subject = "New Case";
cs.Origin = "Phone";
cs.ESB__c = '{!ESB__c.Id}';
var result = sforce.connection.create([cs]);
if(result[0].getBoolean("success")){
    window.location.href = "/"+result[0].id+"/e";
}else{ 
    alert("failed to create account " + result[0]);
}
```

Comment: That worked great! Thanks Saroj. One more bonus thing: how can i get it to land on the newly created case? Right now, after clicking New Case (this custom button), nothing happens, and the user is presented with the same ESB record. I would like it to go to the edit page of the newly created case. Can that be done? I have added the following line, so at least the page is refreshed: window.location.reload();

Comment: Please find my updated answer.